# MAMP, APC - apc_exists

Tags: php, mamp, apc

I am getting `/src/bootstrap.php - Call to undefined function apc_exists()` in my code.

I enabled APC through MAMP GUI and restarted Apache server. I run version 3.2.1.

PHPInfo says:

```
apc

APC support Emulated
apcu

APCu Support    Enabled
Version 4.0.7
APCu Debugging  Disabled
MMAP Support    Enabled
MMAP File Mask  no value
Serialization Support   php
Revision    $Revision: 328290 $
Build Date  Apr 9 2015 19:00:54
Directive   Local Value Master Value
apc.coredump_unmap  Off Off
apc.enable_cli  Off Off
apc.enabled On  On
apc.entries_hint    4096    4096
apc.gc_ttl  3600    3600
apc.mmap_file_mask  no value    no value
apc.preload_path    no value    no value
apc.rfc1867 Off Off
apc.rfc1867_freq    0   0
apc.rfc1867_name    APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_prefix  upload_ upload_
apc.rfc1867_ttl 3600    3600
apc.serializer  php php
apc.shm_segments    1   1
apc.shm_size    32M 32M
apc.slam_defense    On  On
apc.smart   0   0
apc.ttl 0   0
apc.use_request_time    On  On
apc.writable    /tmp    /tmp
```

The documentation says that apc_exists is enabled as of (PECL apc >= 3.1.4) and I run 4.0.7.